# How to make one hover-info included all information on one label on box plots?

Tags: reactjs, plotly

I am new on plotly.

I have a box plot which has 3 values on y axis, and the corresponding text is min, medium, and max. How can I add text on each of this values and display it on one box while I hover on that point?

What I need to do is similar to this: 
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1847

However, I need a real example for box plot.

Answer (score 0):

I found that link where it says that it is not supported the text on hover info on box plots..

https://community.plot.ly/t/boxplot-hoverinfo-text-not-display/1959